# How can you test conditional CSS meant for an iPhone on a desktop browser like safari, chrome, or firefox?

Tags: iphone, css, cross-browser

Specifically, the "max-device-width:" condition

Comment: if you're building something for public consumption, it's always best to test with the actual device / software it's intended for.

Comment: I know you asked for one meant for the browser, but if you're using a Windows machine I've found http://www.electricplum.com/ to be really good.  It's a pretty lightweight application too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're on a Mac, you can use the iPhone simulator that comes with XCode. I've also used a Firefox add-on called "Modify Headers" and I send iPhone headers, however, that may not help much with max-device-width.

Answer (score 1):

For mac or PC, if you can upload your files to any temporary server, you can check the results online in TestiPhone: http://www.testiphone.com/

> This is a web browser based simulator for quickly testing your iPhone
>   web applications. This tool has been so far tested and working using
>   Internet Explorer 7, FireFox 2 and Safari 3.

Comment: Maybe not. It must misidentify itself cause it does not trigger the mobile version of web apps and gets served the desktop version.

Answer (score 1):

The firefox plugin Developer toolbar let you change the browser size with just one click to the device size. I bet there is plugins like that to the other browsers. If you can't find that to all browsers then I suggest that you just upload your code to a server and surf to it using an iPhone.